# Ajax response status 200 but shows error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm getting status as 200 but it's printing message present inside error message `alert("error...");`. Why so?

```
function makeSelect() {
    var blouseoption = document.querySelector('input[name="blouseoption"]:checked').value;
    var url = "http://dukano.co/sakhidev/retailon/productoption/values";
    alert(url);
    var jsondata = $j('#customoption').serialize();     
    alert("jsondata: " + JSON.stringify(jsondata));

    $j.ajax({    
        type : 'POST',
        url : url,
        data : jsondata,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(response) {
            console.log("calling");
            console.log(response);
            alert("call success");
            alert("response data:" + JSON.stringify(response));  
            if (response.status == 200) {
                console.log("yes");
            } else if (response.status == "error") {
                console.log("no");
            }

        },
        error : function(response) {
            alert("error...");
            alert("response:" + JSON.stringify(response));
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Magento's controller function returning json value

```
  public function valuesAction(){
            $blouseoption = $this->getRequest()->getParam('blouseoption');
            $sareefinishing = $this->getRequest()->getParam('sareefinishing');
            $data = array( 'sfinishing' => $sareefinishing, 'layout' => $this->getLayout());
            Mage::dispatchEvent('product_custom_option', $data);
            $jsonData = json_encode(array($blouseoption, $sareefinishing));
            $this->getResponse()->clearHeaders()
             ->setHeader('Content-type','application/json',true);
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($jsonData));
            $this->getResponse()->sendResponse();
    }
```

Comment: you have mentioned a dataType as 'json". Are you sure ajax call is returning json object even if it is a blank object. jQuery ajax here is expecting an json response. for a quick check put 'text' instead of json as dataType and run if calling gets printed means you got the problem.

Comment: catch your response as `error : function(jqXHR,errorThrown,status) {console.log(jqXHR.responseText)}`

Comment: I've added php code which is returning json value. please check updates.

Comment: after changing this problem still persist? if yes try as per my previous comment put dataType as text instead of json and see if calling alert is getting printed on console or not.

Comment: So load your debugger and determine what the error is. This question contains neither reproduction steps (no, a Magento PHP function code dump doesn't count) nor a concrete problem description. -1

Comment: I've tried `error : function(jqXHR,errorThrown,status) {console.log(jqXHR.responseText)}`, it's returning nul value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using

```
 dataType: "json"
```

this evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object.any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown.

This means that if server returns invalid JSON with a `200 OK status` then `jQuery` fires the error function and set the `textStatus` parameter to `"parsererror"`.

Make sure that the server returns valid JSON. empty response is also considered invalid JSON; you could return {} or null for example which validate as JSON.
try to check the textStatus in the error.

```
 error : function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown)
   {console.log(textStatus)}
```

if this prints "parsererror" then of course you have problem with your returning json. please check that.

[More Info](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I've tried `error : function(jqXHR,errorThrown,status) {console.log(jqXHR.responseText)}`, it's returning nul value.

Comment: `error : function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown)
   {console.log(textStatus)}` prints `error`

Comment: are you doing cross domain request. if so try enabling crossDomain :true

Comment: @Iceberg: Nope, I'm not doing cross domain request.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative answer**

Instead of returning status 200 with empty response, you can return status 204 and not return any response. Status 204 is for `No Content`. JQuery should not throw any error in this case.